# Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Assuming the following two tables, 'user' and 'friends';

```
'user'
column: id
column: name

'friends'
column: user_id
column: user2_id
```

Both columns in the friends table correspond to the user table id column.

Now I can simply find users by partial name with the following;

```
$query='jim';
$result=$em->getRepository('\User\Entity\User')
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.name like :match')
        ->setParameter('match', $query.'%')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Now assuming an object of \User\Entity\User userA, how would I do a partial string match for all users that userA is *not* friends with already ?

## **EDIT** *Added the Entity definitions*

```
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_key", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $name;
}


/**
 * UserFriends
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_friends", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id_key", columns={"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="friend_user_id_key", columns={"friend_user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserFriends
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \User\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $friendUser;

    /**
     * @var \User\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $user;
}`
```

Comment: Instead of table columns, can you please post your entity definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We’ll do it in two steps. First, we find out which users they *are* friends with, then we do a query excluding them.

First, we retrieve an ID list of the user’s friends:

```
$friendIds = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT IDENTITY(uf.user)
    FROM User\Entity\UserFriends uf
    WHERE uf.user = :id")
->setParameter("id", $userId) // $userId is the ID of the target user
->getResult();

$friendIds = array_map("current", $friendIds); // needed for flattening the array
```

Now we simply query the user table, excluding the IDs of our friends:

```
$notMyFriends = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT u
    FROM User\Entity\User u
    WHERE u.id != :ownid 
    AND WHERE u.id NOT IN (:friends)")
->setParameter("ownid", $userId) // $userId is the ID of the target user
->setParameter("friends", $friendIds)
->getResult();
```

I’m using plain DQL here, but if you prefer the query builder, you can as well rewrite it to a QB method chain.

(All of the above is from the top of my head, hope it works. If not, please leave a comment and I'll try to fix it.)

---

By the way, please let me give you a few hints regarding your entity classes:

- Entity classes should always be in singular `UserFriends` → `UserFriend`.
- all of your `name="foobar"` annotation parameters are redundant, as Doctrine will auto-name your tables, indices and columns.
- Same goes for the `JoinColumns` … you can omit them altogether, unless you want to explicitely change the default behaviour (which you usually don’t).
- `nullable=true` is the default for an xToOne relation, so it can be omitted, too.
- `nullable=false` and `unique=false` don’t make sense on an ID field. The first is redundant, the second is impossible.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try and report back. Regarding the other suggestions, the entities were auto generated by doctrine from the database tables.

Comment: Glad I could help. Did it work just like this or did you have modify my code? If so, please update my answer with your fixes, so that the next guy can benefit from it, too.

Comment: To preface, I'm not particularly well versed in database queries. My initial solution was to use two queries, per your solution. I thought that may be inefficient, so I posted here to see if anyone better versed than I could provide a solution with a single query. Your answer confirmed what I already had; two queries. I thought I'd ask here simply for confirmation that a single query wasn't possible.

Comment: Actually, I think it could be done with an JOIN. But, to be honest, to post a halfway useful example I would have had to implement a test case, but I was too lazy for it. Check the revision history of my post. ;)